# Strange parsing issue

Tags: java, jquery, parsing, servlets

I'm trying to send some data to a servlet and then to get back a `.xls` file from it. In order to do this, I'm using jquery, but I'm facing some strange issues. Let me explain.

Here is how I'm sending the data to the servlet and how I'm supposed to get the generated file back:

```
jQuery.download = function(url, data, method){
                        //url and data options required
                        if( url && data ){ 
                            //data can be string of parameters or array/object
                            data = typeof data == 'string' ? data : jQuery.param(data);
                            //split params into form inputs
                            var inputs = '';
                            jQuery.each(data.split('&'), function(){ 
                                var pair = this.split('=');
                                inputs+='<input type="hidden" name="'+ pair[0] +'" value="'+ pair[1] +'" />'; 
                            });
                            //send request
                            jQuery('<form action="'+ url +'" method="'+ (method||'post') +'">'+inputs+'</form>')
                            .appendTo('body').submit().remove();
                        };
                    };

 download = function () {     
                        var a = this.mainData();        
                        var b = JSON.stringify(a);
                        console.log(b);
                        what = "test",
                            obj = $.extend({WrJOB: "xlsExport", mainData:  b}, tJS.getCommonPostData());                        
                        var data = $.param(obj); //.replace(/\+/g, '%20'); its just a test
                        $.download('/myapp/AppProxy', data);
                     },
```

A button in my html is calling the `download` function wich is sending some JSON data to the servlet. In my case it is `var b`.

I'm pretty sure that there is an encoding issue, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Please, help me with this strange problem, I'm already working many hours on it and I can not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unescape your output at some point. I would advise to do it on servlet side.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! There are some disadvantages when you're a junior developer. HUGE thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the servlet is receiving it encoded for a URL.  You might be able to decode it on the servlet side if you have control over the code on the servlet.

For instance, in PHP, using urldecode()

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
$.extend({URLEncode:function(c){var o='';var x=0;c=c.toString();var r=/(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*)/;while(x<c.length){var m=r.exec(c.substr(x));  if(m!=null && m.length>1 && m[1]!=''){o+=m[1];x+=m[1].length;  }else{if(c[x]==' ')o+='+';else{var d=c.charCodeAt(x);var h=d.toString(16);  o+='%'+(h.length<2?'0':'')+h.toUpperCase();}x++;}}return o;},URLDecode:function(s){var o=s;var binVal,t;var r=/(%[^%]{2})/;while((m=r.exec(o))!=null && m.length>1 && m[1]!=''){b=parseInt(m[1].substr(1),16);t=String.fromCharCode(b);o=o.replace(m[1],t);}return o;}});

jQuery.each(data.split('&'), function(){
   var pair = this.split('=');
   inputs+='<input type="hidden" name="'+ pair[0] +'" value="'+ jQuery.URLDecode(pair[1]) +'" />';         
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you urlencode your data twice. First explicitly in your javascript, then implicitly when creating the form. The browser will be "nice" to you and urlencode the input parameters before doing the request.

Either decode the parameters before adding them as input values or change the way you build your data to avoid the explicit encoding.